# Count the number of all possible distinct 3-digit numbers given a String array

Tags: java, algorithm, count, time-complexity, unique

Below is my code for counting the number of distinct 3 digit strings which works correctly, HOWEVER, I would like to optimize this code to where I can improve the time complexity. Can someone help me w/ this?

input: [1,2,1,4]

output: 12

Thanks.

```
static int countUnique(String [] arr)
{
    Set<String> s = new TreeSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<arr.length; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k<arr.length; k++)
            {
                if (i!=j && j != k && i!=k)
                    s.add((arr[i] +""+arr[j]+""+arr[k]));
            }
        }
    }
    return s.size();
}
```

Comment: Instead of using *brute force* you need to think about *algorithms*. You may want to start here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-combinatorial-algorithms or Google "java combinatorics tutorial" for other sources.

Comment: I'd say your problem seems like pure math. As a hint: basics of combinatorics should be sufficient.

Comment: @Ecto Basic combinatorics is not actually sufficient for this problem, even though it is for some similar looking ones.

Comment: Why are your inputs strings? Do you need to worry about the case where the same output string could be produced by multiple different sets of input strings (for example, your input is `[1, 12, 23, 3, 4]` and you could produce `1234` from either `12` + `3` + `4` or `1` + `23` + `4`)? Or are you just using strings and concatenation as a simple way to produce a comparable value for the `Set`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the OP stated that their code works correctly. The elements of the input are therefore single digits as indicated by the OP's correct code. The task is limited to 3-digit length.

Comment: I added random testing to my code, comparing with your own brute force implementation, to show that it works.

Comment: @btilly doesn't my answer use just basic combinatorics? :)

Comment: @גלעדברקן Not in a form that you would want to do by hand if the input string was long enough that `O(n^3)` is slow on a computer.

Comment: @גלעדברקן The OP already had an `O(n^3)` solution in the question, and wanted to improve the time complexity.  So the answer only matters for cases when that cubic solution is too slow.

Comment: @btilly I think you're saying, yes, the answer uses combinatorics but still relies on the computer since for cases where it would be more efficient than `O(n^3)`, it would be impractical to do by hand. I would second that.

Comment: @גלעדברקן We are in agreement. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `O(n)` solution:

Iterate over each distinct available digit in turn.

(A) Add 1 if there are three instances of it, accounting for one string of three of this digit.

(B) If there are two instances of it, add 3 times the number of digits already iterated over, accounting for 3 choose 2 ways to arrange two instances of this digit with one other digit already iterated over.

(C) Add the number of ways we can pick two of the digits seen so far, accounting for arranging just one instance of this digit with each of those.

(D) Finally, add to our record of the counts of ways to arrange two digits: if there are two instances of this digit, add 3 choose 2 = 3, accounting for just arranging two instances of this digit. Also add (2 * 3 choose 2 = 6) times the number of digits already iterated over, accounting for the number of ways to arrange this digit with another already seen.

For example:

```
1 2 1 4

1 -> D applies, add 3 to the two-digit-arrangements count
  11x, 1x1, x11

2 -> C applies, add 3 to result
  112, 121, 211
     D applies, add 6 to the two-digit-arrangements count (total 9)
  12x, 1x2, x12, 21x, 2x1, x21
  
4 -> C applies, add 9 to result

Result 12
```

JavaScript code with random tests, comparing with your brute force approach:

```js
function f(A){
  const counts = {};
  
  for (let a of A)
    counts[a] = counts[a] ? -~counts[a] : 1;

  let result = 0;
  let numTwoDigitArrangements = 0;
  let numSeen = 0;
  
  for (let d of Object.keys(counts)){
    if (counts[d] > 2)
      result += 1;

    if (counts[d] > 1)
      result += 3 * numSeen;

    result += numTwoDigitArrangements;

    if (counts[d] > 1)
      numTwoDigitArrangements += 3;
        
    numTwoDigitArrangements += 6 * numSeen;

    numSeen = numSeen + 1;
  }
  
  return result;
}


function bruteForce(arr){
  const s = new Set();
    
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    for (let j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
      for (let k=0; k<arr.length; k++){
        if (i != j && j != k && i != k)
          s.add((arr[i] + "" + arr[j]+ "" + arr[k]));
      }
    }
  }
  
  return s.size;
}


// Random tests
var numTests = 500;
var maxLength = 25;

for (let i=0; i<numTests; i++){
  const n = Math.ceil(Math.random() * maxLength);
  const A = new Array(n);
  
  for (let j=0; j<n; j++)
    A[j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    
  const _f = f(A);
  const _bruteForce = bruteForce(A);
  
  if (_f != _bruteForce){
    console.log('Mismatch found:');
    console.log('' + A);
    console.log(`f: ${ _f }`);
    console.log(`brute force: ${ _bruteForce }`);
  }
}

console.log('Done testing.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is by Backtracking algorithm. Any combination or permutation kind of problem can be solved using Backtracking.
Here is some information on Backtracking algorithm - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Note: This is not most optimized solution nor O(n) solution. This solution is O(n! * n). But there are many opportunities to make it more optimized.

Java code using Backtracking:

```
int countUniqueOpt(String[] arr) {

        //Set to avoid duplicates
        Set<String> resultList = new HashSet<>();

        backtracking(arr, 3, resultList, new ArrayList<>());

        return resultList.size();
    }

    void backtracking(String[] arr, int k, Set<String> resultList, List<Integer> indexList) {

        if (indexList.size() == k) {
            String tempString = arr[indexList.get(0)] + arr[indexList.get(1)] + arr[indexList.get(2)];
            resultList.add(tempString);
        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (!indexList.contains(i)) {
                    indexList.add(i);

                    backtracking(arr, k, resultList, indexList);

                    indexList.remove(indexList.size() - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```